# Is there a way to change the width of a website using css? - HTML

Tags: html, css

I was starting to make a website however I want it to be 1200px wide.

This is my code so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Wesbite Css.css">
        <title>Website Task</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
#header {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
        width: 1200px;
}
```

The width change in my CSS code does not affect the website

Comment: `Wesbite Css.css` <-- no space in name or you will have some surprise in the future

Comment: What’s your css file actually called - does it have the same website/wesbite typo as the html? Is eg the background colour working, is it just the width that isn’t, or all of it?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing well, but you have some code to change.

Between your body tag and your div tag in your HTML code, add another div tag. Call this one container.
This is basically the "container" of your website.
Your code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Wesbite Css.css">
        <title>Website Task</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then go to CSS and then remove the width attribute.
Add this to your code:

```
#container{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And now it should work!

Comment: why he should add an extra wrapper?

Comment: I learnt this from my High School teacher that it's the most convenient way to change the width of the whole website

Comment: that doesn't explain why his code is not working, technically your code should produce the same output as his code. It's not about best practise but *why his code is not working*

Comment: The styles for `#container` should be on `<body>` unless you have a strong use case that would require an extra element.